# Salesforce mobile web experience retirement

Tags: mobilesdk

We would like to confirm if custom apps using Salesforce SDK accessing Salesforce standard features (including Salesforce UIs) through web view  will be affected by the article below?
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349471&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Only the mobile browsing experience is being removed. The standard app as well as any custom apps won't be affected by this feature being removed, as they do not use the mobile web experience (found by going to https://login.salesforce.com/ on your phone in Google Chrome, Safari, etc).

Comment: I brought your clarification to our team and they asked me to give you more details about the scenario.

Let’s consider an hybrid app using ionic/cordova + salesforce mobile sdk:
There will be a custom sales journey on which the UI will be build from scratch. Besides the custom sales journey we intend to access standard salesforce features (same as Salesforce 1) through cordova web view.
This scenario can be impacted by mobile web experience retirement?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marcos It sounds like both of those things will be impacted by this change.  As of today we only recommend showing Visualforce pages in the cordova webview.